# Git: inter-branch dependency graph/list

Tags: git

I sometimes have a few related feature branches, with some building on others, like

```
                o feature-B
               /
              /
          o--o feature-A
         /
        /
master o
        \
         o feature-C
```

I'd like to display a graph showing which branches depend on which, but having a hard time getting `git log --graph` to yield what I want.

The following fails to show the relationships between the branches.

```
$ git log --graph --format='%h%d' ^master feature-{A,B,C}

* 801ecee208 (HEAD -> feature-B)
* e568acd804 (feature-A)
* f49ecc9e28
* a42d73d4bc (feature-C)
```

Changing `^master` to `^master~` improves things, but forces me to include an earlier commit I don't care about (`origin/some-earlier-branch`).

```
$ git log --graph --format='%h%d' ^master~ feature-{A,B,C}

* 801ecee208 (HEAD -> feature-B)
* e568acd804 (feature-A)
* f49ecc9e28
| * a42d73d4bc (feature-C)
|/
* 67cf54dd0e (master)
* 40b72ecc6a (origin/some-earlier-branch)
```

That's pretty close to what I want, though it would be nice to omit that last line.

What I'm really trying to get is a sort of manifest listing which branches depend on which other branches. Something like

```
feature-A -> master
feature-B -> feature-A
feature-C -> master
```

so I can generate a graphviz graph of the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not actually *dependencies* (although that probably does not matter for your purpose).

Consider this brief variant, for instance:

```
    o   <-- foo
   /
  o
 /
o       <-- master
```

Now we use `git branch bar foo~1` to add a branch label `bar`:

```
    o   <-- foo
   /
  o     <-- bar
 /
o       <-- master
```

It seems odd to say that `foo` "depends on" `bar` when `bar` can wink into and out of existence at any time.  What you need instead—this will inform your thinking when you go to build your graph—is to treat this as "`foo` *shares reachable commits with* `bar`".  That is, what you will want here is to make a list of commits and their parent IDs, then correlate the various IDs.  If some ID is *reachable from* a branch tips A, B, and C, that commit shares its reason-for-existing with those three branch names.

Now you need only generate two lists:

- the hash ID of each branch tip, and
- the hash ID of each commit reachable *from* each branch tip, excluding all commits reachable from whatever names you wish to exclude (such as `master`)

which this, for instance, should do (I have not tested it):

```
for name in $names; do
    echo $name $(git rev-parse $name)
done
echo --
git rev-list --parents $names --not $exclude
```

The first set of lines, up to the `--`, gives you name-to-ID mappings for the branch tips (assuming, of course, that all names in `$names` are valid).  The second set of lines, after `--` to EOF, gives you commit-IDs followed by the IDs of all parents of that commit (one for regular commits, two or more for merge commits, and no parents for root commits).  The `--not $exclude` makes sure you don't get any commits reachable from the list of names in `$exclude`.

Note that multiple branch names may point to a single branch tip commit, and if all branch tips are "at or behind" the exclusion(s), the second list of ID-sets may be empty.